# Cannot place order with saved cards

Tags: magento2, error, braintree, vault

I currently have an issue placing orders with saved cards using Vault for Braintree. With a bit of debugging, I can see the following error:

> *Public hash should be defined in /vendor/magento/module-vault/Model/Method/Vault.php:498*

I can see when looking at the Request Payload for '**payment-information**', public_hash is blank and returns a 400 error. This is on Magento 2.2.2, and just to state, placing orders with new card details works fine, but when using the same card again as a saved card, it fails.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any solution to this yet?

Comment: Having the same issue. Anyone have a solution for this?